# Need help developing SQL query

Tags: asp.net, sql, security, sdf

I’m trying to develop a SQL query to help me extract some data from my ASP.NET based website. I'm working on a SQL compact database (sdf) on my ASP.NET based website using WebMatrix.

I’m trying to implement a code in my website to do monthly spring cleaning of the database. I need to delete those accounts which were created by the user but never activated. So to free up the user IDs and manage database size, I thought I’d run a query on the database to get me those accounts which have not been confirmed by the user yet and their creation date has passed 20 days.

The database structure is that my user’s table is called “Users”. It has a UserID (autonumber), Email, FullName, etc. fields.

The table created by ASP’s WebSecurity is called “webpages_Membership”. It has UserID (autonumber), CreationDate, IsConfirmed (whether account has been activated), etc. fields.

I’m not good at developing SQL queries. The problem I’m facing is that when a user is deleted using the Membership.DeleteUser method with argument set to DeleteAllRecords, it deletes the relevant user’s row in my Users table, whereas it does nothing in its own table “webpages_Membership”. When a user tries to sign-in, it simply checks if the Email (the userid) exists in my Users table. So in the long run, there are accounts appearing in “webpages_Membership” which do not exist in “Users” table because they were deleted. People who are familiar with the behavior of WbeSecurity must’ve experienced all this above.

I’m trying to develop a query that will lookup the “webpages_Membership” table, get me those rows which have IsConfirmed field set to False (meaning those accounts not activated yet), and ensure that the UserID field in "webpages_Membership" also exists in "Users" table (this will ensure account is not previously deleted).

Comment: Be precise in writing the question,

Comment: I had to write the background about how the WebSecurity code is behaving. Its because of its behaviour that I'm unable to write a suitable query for it.

Comment: Post the code you have until now to start with something. And if possible improve the way you show the table structure so it can be possible to use it. And even better if you also post some data to test.

Comment: I've developed a query on my own using MS Access: 
`SELECT users.ID, webpages_Membership.IsConfirmed 
FROM webpages_Membership, users
WHERE (((users.ID)=[webpages_Membership].[ID]) AND ((webpages_Membership.IsConfirmed)=True));`
It seems to be giving me weird results.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems too localised to the OP's requirements, it is not explained in a fashion that might generalise it to other people's requirements, and there's no code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select wm.* from webpages_Membership wm inner join Users u
on wm.UserID = u.UserID 
Where wm.IsConfirmed = 'false'
and DATEADD(dd,20,wm.CreationDate) <= getdate()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your query on my dummy database structure inside MS Access. It gives me an error Undefined function GetDate(). Is this function not available on MS Access?

Comment: I've applied your query in my SQL compact database (which recognizes the GetDate). Although the query is returning the relevant rows, but the date function is not properly working. Its returning rows with creationdate even less than 20. I need the accounts which have surpassed 20 days since creation date.

Comment: try this updated query.I was adding 20days to the getdate insted of createdondate

Comment: I think that's still not right. Let me explain again. The query should fetch records which have been created more than 20 days ago from today's date. I've changed something by myself. I think it should be: `WHERE wm.CreationDate <= DateAdd(day, -20, GetDate());`

Comment: Anyway it works now.  Thanks Anand and everyone. I couldn't have reached till here by myself.